# UIProgressView when putting image into UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I wonder, how could I display UIProgressView in this case:
I do photo with UIImagePickerController then in method `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`
I save the picture to UIImage object (outputImage) and hide controller, and when modalView/controller with camera is disappeared I have such code:

```
        NSLog(@"Image is width: %f height: %f", outputImage.size.width, outputImage.size.height);

        //FLIP PICTURE FROM FACETIME CAMERA
        if((outputImage.size.width == 480 && outputImage.size.height == 640) || (outputImage.size.width == 640 && outputImage.size.height == 480)) {
            outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:outputImage.CGImage
                                        scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];}

        //RESIZE TO 1000x1000
        outputImage = [self scaleAndCropToSize:outputImage toSize:CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)];

        NSLog(@"Now image is width: %f height: %f", outputImage.size.width, outputImage.size.height);

        //CUTING OUT TO MASK
        outputImage = [self maskImage:outputImage withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"]];

        //ADDING SHADOW
        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

        CGPoint thumbPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        [outputImage drawAtPoint:thumbPoint];

        UIImage* shadow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shadow.png"];

        CGPoint starredPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        [shadow drawAtPoint:starredPoint];

        UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        outputImage = result;

        //ADDING TO UIIMAGEVIEW (PREVIEW)
        preview.image = outputImage;
```

While photo is being put into UIImageView, it takes some time. In this time I'd like to display progress view. How can I do that?

EDIT: I thought to place above code in some method and then somehow implement progressview, that would base on method completion time. But dunno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `UIProgressView` as its difficult to know how much time it will take to perform image operations.

you can try this [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Put this code in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

```
MBProgressHUD *HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];

HUD.labelText = @"Saving Image...";

[self.view  addSubview:HUD];

HUD.delegate = self;

[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(savingPicture:) onTarget:self withObject:selectedImage animated:YES];
```

and put your resize/crop image operations code in savingPicture method.

Answer (score 0):

Progress views are more appropriate when you are running a loop and you know what percentage of the work is being completed, to show the progress in the progress bar. In this case you can show  a UIActivityIndicator instead, until your image is ready to be put on the image view.